# Priority Queue (using pairs<int,int> ) Top element according to for loop iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, priority-queue

I want a priority queue such that first it should be done on basis of first element (increasing order)and when clash occurs then on basis of second element(decreasing order). I came up with the following code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


struct Compare {
    constexpr bool operator()(pair<int, int> const & a,
                              pair<int, int> const & b) const noexcept
    { return a.first > b.first || (a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second); }
};

int main()
{
    priority_queue<pair<int,int>,
                   std::vector<pair<int,int> >,
                   Compare> Q;
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        Q.push(make_pair(a,b));
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        pair<int,int> m;
        m=Q.top();
        if(m.first <= i)
          cout<<m.first<<" "<<m.second<<"\n";
        Q.pop();
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the for loop I want that pair to be on top from all those pair who satisfy the condition :

```
pair<ll,ll> m;
m.first <= i
```

For eg -

```
N=8, Pairs :
1 100
1 300
2 500
4 800
3 500
4 100
8 1000
2 700
```

Then the following code :

```
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
     pair<int,int> m;
     m=Q.top();
     cout<<m.first<<" "<<m.second<<"\n";
    // Q.pop();
 }
```

should give following result:

```
1 300  (for i=1, it should have 2 choices : (1,100),(1,300) and select (1,300) )
2 700  (for i=2 it should have 4 choices : (1,100),(1,300),(2,500),(2,700) and select (2,700))
2 700  (for i=3 it should have 5 choices : (1,100),(1,300),(2,500),(2,700),(3,500) and select (2,700))
4 800  (for i=4,5,6,7 it should have 7 choices : (1,100),(1,300),(2,500),(2,700),(3,500),(4,100),(4,800) and select (4,800)).
8 1000  (for i=8 it should have 8 choices : (1,100),(1,300),(2,500),(2,700),(3,500),(4,100),(4,800),(8,1000) and select (8,1000)).
```

I hope the example is clear now.

The problem is because `Priority_Queue` prioritize First element according to my `Compare` function  and thus it chooses `(1 300)` instead of `(2 700)` for `i=2,3`.

What should I do to change the top element in Priority Queue with iterator of for loop ? Can someone help me out ?

Comment: [I get different output](http://rextester.com/JMX64781) than what you claim. It looks correct to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry. the `pop()` was to be commented out. You can check now. http://rextester.com/QYG13206

Comment: `was to be commented out` - well, what *do* you expect, then? Nothing changes the queue, why should the output change?

Comment: @greybeard That's what I need help with. I tried reinserting the `top` element with increased value of `first` value in the `pair<int,int>` but when I search for next `i`the others pair whose value wasn't incremented become `top` element. If there's any way to increment `first` value of all `pair<int,int>` whose `pair.first() <=i` , it would solve the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over the items that are in the priority queue, without removing them from the queue? If you want to do that, you'll need to create a derived object and access the protected `C` member, which references the container that holds the items. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @JimMischel That likely won't do the OP much good though. Items in that container are not in sorted order.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you simply want elements sorted according to your comparison, insert them into a plain old `std::vector` and sort them with `std::sort`. "I want a priority queue but I don't want to pop elements from it" makes no sense as a problem statement - adding and removing elements is the whole point of a queue.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: True enough. Like you, I have no idea what the OP is really trying to do.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have to pop out the elements but later.Right now,it concerns about ordering as I mentioned in the included elaborated example. I hope it is clear now what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you expecting the order of the entire queue to change based on the top item? I'm afraid it's still not very clear to me. It feels like the desire to use a priority queue is a red herring and what you really want to do is search/filter based on an external value.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I just want the Priority Queue to select the top element from the pool of pairs whose `Pair.First <=i`. Like in the given example, `for (i=3)` It will select `(1,300) as (1<3)` but it should consider `(1,100),(1,300)(2,700), (2,500),(3,500) and select (2,700)` (on basis of second element) as `1,2 and 3 are less than equal to 3(for i=3)`.

Comment: I don't understand. `1 300` is the best pair according to your comparison function, and it also satisfies the condition of `1 <= i` for all `i`. Why again `1 300` repeated 8 times is *not* the correct output? It appears to satisfy all your conditions. I don't understand the logic by which you arrive at, say, `2 700` being the expected second line of the output.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  I want the top element to be whose `Pair.second` is the highest among all pairs whose `Pair.first <=i`. I couldn't tweak comparison function to my needs. Please refer the previous comment as I explained in it `(2,700)` should be the answer as `(700)` is highest among `(100,300,500,700)`.

Comment: What if `lhs.second == rhs.second`, are those sorted by `lhs.first < rhs.first` or some other method? This gives the output you're interested in, but I didn't use a priority queue since that didn't make any sense to me. http://ideone.com/oVdtcZ

Comment: [Something like this](http://rextester.com/WQN19714), then. `std::priority_queue` is of no help with this problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, this works. Thanks.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah, It works as I want. There's just one thing. Can you explain me a little bit how your algorithm works ?

Comment: [Here's a simpler version](http://rextester.com/APNTO78233). Hopefully, it's easier to understand. We leave figuring out how it works as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

*`What should I do to change the top element in Priority Queue`*
If the change doesn't affect the order, just modify `Q.top()`.
If the change might affect the order, `Q.push()` a modified `Q.pop()`.

Comment: Change does affect the order and I have tried it. I will tell you the problem in it. When `for (i=1)` , the top element would be `(1,300)` but 'for (i=2)` it should be `(2,700)` instead of `(1,300)` again. For this I tried `Push(2,300)` i.e. by changing `(1,300) to (2,300)` but the problem is `(1,100)` will be picked as it wasn't modified as I can't simply know which more pairs are to be modified. Similarly `for (i=3)` `(1 100)(1 300)(2 500)(2 700)` need to be modified to `(3 100)(3 300)(3 500)(3 700)` only but I could only modify `(2 700)` as it was the top element.